# Webpack disable hashing of image name on output

Tags: angular, webpack

After building my angular4 application, webpack changed my image name from `bg_node_new.png` to `bg_node_new.3746bc3ac9b1bf77d2aff2c2df901a48.png`.

my webpack.config code is:

```
(function(module) {

    const path = require('path');
    const npm_cmd = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
    const p = !(require('yargs').argv.p || false);
    let config;

    module.exports = function(env) {

        let cmds = npm_cmd.split(":");
        const cmd = cmds.length >= 2 ? cmds[1] : null;
        const mod = cmds.length >= 3 ? cmds[2] : null;
        const aot = cmds.length >= 4 ? cmds[3] : null;

        const options = {
            p:!p,
            mod:mod,
            aot:aot,
            env:env,
            ngv:2,
            ctx:path.resolve(__dirname, "../../../../..")
        }
        //console.log(options);

        switch (cmd) {
          case 'app': 
            console.log("Building app");
            config = require('./wp.app')(options);
            break;
          case 'lib': 
            console.log("Building lib");
            config = require('./wp.lib')(options);
            break;
          case 'mod':
            console.log("Building mod");
            config = require('./wp.mod')(options);
            break
          default:
            console.log("Building app");
            config = require('./wp.app')(options);
            break;
        }

        return config;
    }

})(module);
```

Due to this, the image is not rendering in my app. how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You can disable that in webpack. Share your webpack config.

Comment: [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671342/how-to-load-image-files-with-webpack-file-loader) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469831/file-loader-changed-image-file-name-but-not-the-file-name-in-html-file) to see if helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: And other webpack configs

Comment: I have  wp.app.js, ap.base.js, wp.lib.js, wp.mode.js, wp.test.js

Comment: Can you shars these files on some online repo? Github e.g ?

Comment: Sure, I will share it.

Comment: you can have a look at this link - https://embed.plnkr.co/mlNmg8qP9DEhwNktZNc7/

Comment: I tried changing `'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'` to `'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'`. from wp.base.js, but still no luck.

Comment: it's removing  [hash] values on font now, but it's not converting images at all :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATED After OP's comment:**

In your `wp.base.js`, remove `[hash]` from the following:

```
const raw_file_loader = {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico|otf)$/,
    use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
}
```

---

**ORIGINAL Answer:**

If you share your webpack config, I'll be ablr to answer better. However, Find a config like this in your `webpack.config`,

```
{
  test: /.*\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '/images/[name]_[hash:7].[ext]',
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

... and remove the `[hash]` part. Just keep it like this:

> name: '/images/[name].[ext]',

Answer (score 0):

This is because of hashing Angular does at the time of build to stop that use , provided you are using Angular CLI

```
 ng build --prod --output-hashing none
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. we are not using Angular CLI :(

Comment: @Sarav what are you using ?

Comment: @Rahul, webpack

Comment: @Sarav cli also uses webpack now so i got confused with it

Comment: Yes I know, but he is using webpack.config

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem in React project, I set webpack.config.js like this

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
                name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
            },
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also need to turn off source handling in your html loader

```
            {
            test: /\.html$/i,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: { minimize: false, sources: false }
                }
            ]
        }
```