# Preloading fonts using angular CLI

Tags: angular, optimization

> **EDIT: AFAIK This is not a duplicate of [Webpack disable hashing of image name on output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809887/webpack-disable-hashing-of-image-name-on-output) because:**
>
> - **webpack.config is no longer editable in current angularCli versions.**
> - **I want to keep the hash on the file names for cache busting.**

I'm using Angular and I would like to preload my fonts, i tried using

```
  <link rel="preload" href="assets/someFont.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

However angular hashes my fonts during the build process, so my font will be copied to the root folder and renamed to look something like this.

```
myFont.e31fcf1885e371e19f57.woff2
```

and my @fontface reference will point to that font.

So in the end I'm actually loading the same font twice instead of preloading the font, since the browser sees different URLs

- /assets/myFont.woff2
- myFont.e31fcf1885e371e19f57.woff2

How can I preload the fonts and keep the hashing functionality (for cache-busting)?

Comment: If I understand correctly That answer asumes I have control over webpack.config, I dont. AngularCLI no longer provides it.@jcuypers

Comment: I disagree, this is not a duplicate question. It is a different and unique question. Just because the solution *might* be the same, it doesn't make it a duplicate. @jcuypers

Comment: ok fair enough.   Anyway I didnt fiddle around with it enough in order to be of assistance.  having said that i partly remember i was in the same webpack missing story and go to something like an alternate build system to allows for changes:  ngx-build-plus https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus  .  maybe this can help you

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: not really. I ended up using fonts in CDNs rather than using local ones.

Answer (score 8):

Use an absolute path to your assets folder when defining the font, this will prevent hashing of the font file on deployment:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('/assets/fonts/open-sans.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Then add a hard link to the font file in your `index.html`:

```
    ...
    <link rel="preload" href="/assets/fonts/open-sans.woff" as="font" crossorigin>
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent hashing of font files in the asset folder, you have to include the assets in your **angular.json** like following:

```
"assets": [{
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
          }]
```

instead of

```
"assets": ["src/assets"]
```

Comment: This does not appear to work for `ionic build --prod`.

Comment: This is my current setup, but that's not what im asking (unless there's something im not seeing). "How can I preload the fonts and keep the hashing functionality (for cache-busting)?"

Answer (score -1):

I was helped by the following actions.
Transfer fonts files to assets folder. In styles set absolute path to fonts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'CoreSans';
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('/assets/fonts/CoreSans.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Comment: This is my current setup, but I want to also preload the fonts, not just use them.