# Component CSS @Import conflict

Tags: css, angular

In my login component's CSS, I am importing the following font:

```
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap);
```

In another component in the system, I would like to use this same font but I do not want it applied with italics.  I am importing it in that component's CSS as:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400);
```

In this case, the component is rendering it as if the login page import was being used (the font appears in italics and at 600 font weight).

Until I *refresh the page*.  If I do a refresh, it appears properly at 400 without the bold.

I have tried applying:

```
font-variation-settings: normal;
```

To the `div` containing the text, this has no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could be something related to the caching of css and fonts?
Maybe here you can find the answer.
LINKs:
[Preloading fonts using angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951352/preloading-fonts-using-angular-cli)
[Browser Caching of CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460389/browser-caching-of-css-files)