# Webpack creating hashed file names for images in project

Tags: javascript, webpack

In one of the components in my client/components folder, I am importing three images from the public/images folder.  At some point, webpack created a file for each of the images with hashed names like the following: `0e8f1e62f0fe5b5e6d78b2d9f4116311.png`. If I delete those files, they do not get recreated and I would like for webpack to just use the images that are provided in the images folder.

Now, I am trying to deploy the application on a proxy server and the hash files are being successfully downloaded on page load but the images are not displaying.  I have a hunch that fixing the original webpack issue will fix the issue with the proxy server but I'm not sure about that either.

```
root
├── client
│   └── components
├── database
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── app.js
│   └── index.html     
└── server
    └── server.js
```

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './client/index.js'),
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'env']
        },
      },
      { 
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  }
};
```

The above is my file structure.  I've tried to play around with my current config but I struggle with setting up webpack.  Any help with these issues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem of hashed resources, and adding the **file-loader** only duplicated the build and furthermore the automatic asset management of new webpack versions with the hashed names overridden the **file-loader** URLs to the resource in the .css files, so the image did not show at all, if this is the case with you then you can follow the [instructions here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputassetmodulefilename) on the Webpack website.

You only need to add this prop in the output in *webpack.config.js* and comment file loader if you use it.

```
    output: {
       ...
       assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext]",
    },
```

Comment: Bless you - this was driving me absolutely insane and this comment lead me down the right path to fixing my hashed, duplicated files.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep original filename/path with the following option.

```
{
  test: /\.png$/,
    loaders: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]',
    },
},
```

If you really need to use original file(Not webpack generated file),
you should not use file-loader.
Just upload image file and make `img` tag of that file.

Comment: doesn't work, this works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38469968/1243247