# Why Webpack is duplicating images & hashing malformed images

Tags: image, webpack, build, frontend, assets

I am using Webpack to build my project, but somehow it builds the images twice:

- Once in the *dist/images/* folder, where the build is correct.
- Once again in the root of the build dir i.e. */dist* with wrong hashed names.

These wrong hashed names are then assigned to the element containing the image URL. e.g. if the image is a CSS background image, the wrong name is set to its URL instead of the right one.

**dist/**

[image]

**Result**

This is the result of adding the `background-image: "../images/image.svg"` in *src/styles/app.css*
and my image is located in *src/images/image.svg*.

[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
modules: {
    // CSS
    {
      test: /\.css$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            publicPath: "../images/", //to be able to use url images in my styles
          },
        },
        { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [autoprefixer({ supports: false })],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },

    //SASS
    {
      test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          options: {
            publicPath: "../images/", //to be able to use url images in my styles
          },
        },
        { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [autoprefixer({ supports: false })],
            },
          },
        },
        "sass-loader",
      ],
    },

    //Images
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "images/",
            publicPath: "images/",
          },
        },

        //Compress Images
        {
          loader: "image-webpack-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
},
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "styles/[name].css",
  }),
  new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
    minimizerOptions: {
      plugins: [
        ["jpegtran", { progressive: true }],
        ["optipng", { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
        [
          "svgo",
          {
            plugins: [
              {
                removeViewBox: false,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  }),
]
```

**Notes:**

- The hashed images which are in the */dist* are malformed, and when I open them they cause an error that they are empty.
- I have tried to comment the image optimizers like compressing images and other loaders and plugins listed previously, but this made no change.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with using file-loader with the new webpack versions, so I removed file-loader entirely and relied on the new webpack asset management system, and to fix the hashed webpack image names, I use:

```
output: {
 ...
 assetModuleFilename: "[name][ext]",
},
```

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69181232/14749084) on why this happens